# For vectors $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n), (y_1,y_2,y_n)$, is "$\forall k$ s.t. $x_k>y_k$, $x_k-y_k>C$ vacuously true when $x_k\leq y_k \ \forall k$?

Tags: inequality, logic

Where C is some positive constant?

Basically, I am confused regarding vacuously true statements and trying to use this constructed example to clarify.

The restate the example in slightly more detail, suppose we have two vectors denoted $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n), (y_1,y_2,y_n)$.

The statement in consideration is that, "$\forall k$ , if $x_k>y_k$, then $x_k-y_k>C$.

If it is the case that $x_k\leq y_k \ \  \forall k$, then the statement is vacuously true, correct?

- Basically, is any statement automatically true on an empty set
- (to continue with the above example, if I say "for all vector indices on which $x$ exceeds $y$, the amount by which $x$ exceeds $y$ on that index is at least C), **this statement doesn't guarantee that any such indices exist, so for the statement to be meaningful I would need to address this**)

Comment: How is C quantified (existentially or universally), and are there any restrictions on C? 
If C can be any number, then the statement will be true because $x_k-y_k$ is always greater than at least one number. 
If $x_k\leq y_k$ then the statement is true by the principal of explosion. The only time is the statement will be vacuously true is when there are no $k$ to choose from. That is, when the two vectors are empty ((), and ()).

Comment: C is a positive constant. I don't see how $x_k\leq y_k$ makes the statement true by the principle of explosion, sorry.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

**Vacuous truth**

The phrase vacuous truth is informally used to describe statements of the form (1), which are true because the set $X$ is empty.

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\forall x\in X.P(x)
\end{equation}

It can also refer to statements of the form (2) that happen to be true because no $x\in X$ satisfies Q(x). (See principal of explosion).

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\forall x\in X.Q(x)\rightarrow P(x)
\end{equation}

**Principal of explosion**

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
A\rightarrow B
\end{equation}

Statements of the form (2), are always true whenever $A$ is false. This is due to the definition of implication in symbolic logic.

\begin{array}
{cccc}&A&\lnot A\\
~B &\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}\\
\lnot B~&\color{red}{0}&\color{blue}{1}\\
\end{array}

The above truth table of (3) shows when an implication is true or false. The justification is that (3) should *only* be false when its premises is true, and its consequent is false.

The principal of explosion states that any statement can be proven from a contradiction (falsehood). If $A$ is false in (3), then we have assumed falsehood, and anything may be derived including $B$.

**Your example**

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\forall k\in K. (x_k>y_k)\rightarrow (x_k−y_k>C)
\end{equation}

Often the principal of explosion and vacuous truth are present together. For instance, if the set $X$ is empty in (2), then $\forall x\in X.\lnot Q(x)$ is true vacuously (*no x in X satisfies Q(x)*), and (2) is then true by the principal of explosion.

If $x_k\leq y_k$, then (4) is true by the principal of explosion. It is also vacuously true, since it can be proven that no $k$ satisfy the premises of (4).